# RESTful route for company in country/state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I am trying to find a RESTful route for the following:

-> I have a resource that is Company, and a company is in a particular country and state.

I would like to be able to fetch the following:

-> All companies that are in a Country and State.

I have thought that a good URL to do so would be: `/companies?country=X&state=Y`.  Is that RESTful, or I should do something like:

```
/country/X/state/y/companies
```

Thanks

Comment: `/country/X/state/y/companies` is RESTful, but whether or not it makes sense in the larger context of your API is another story.  In a vacuum, it's a fine choice!

Comment: To me, something like `/companies/{country}/{state}` makes the most sense. This way you can also support getting the companies for a particular country by just leaving the `state` parameter off.

Comment: @justin.chmura But by doing that I wouldn't be able to get a particular country with /companies/:company_id...

Answer (score 1):

If the location is really the primary (only?) grouping of the companies, then they would be included in the resource location, e.g.,

```
/USA/California/Apple - returns a single company
/USA - returns all the USA companies
/USA/California - returns all the USA/California companies
```

But if it's just a search query on a multitude of possible parameters, then /company_search?... might be the appropriate option.